# SoPlex yields wrong answer

Tags: linear-programming, scip

I have an LP in CPLEX LP format, in file `LP.tmp`

```
Maximize
    obj: x0 + 2 x1 + 3 x2 + 4 x3 + 5 x4 + 7 x5
Subject To
    c0: 1 x0 + 1 x1 + 1 x2 + 1 x3 + 1 x4 + 1 x5 + 1 x6 + 1 x7 + 1 x8 = 0
End
```

On this I call `soplex -X -x -o0 -f0 -v3 LP.tmp`
This is obviously unbounded, but calling Soplex gives me the answer (with some other lines).

```
SoPlex status       : problem is solved [optimal]
Solving time (sec)  : 0.00
Iterations          : 0
Objective value     : 0.00000000e+00


Primal solution (name, value):
All other variables are zero (within 1.0e-16). Solution has 0 nonzero entries.
```

Background: Originally, I had objective `0`, but box constraints, and I always got `infeasible`. So I reduced everything, until I arrived at the above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables are non-negative by default in the lp file format, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/LP.html

Therefore, your constraint fixes all variables to 0. As soon as you change the coefficient of any of the variables but x5 to -1 or add a bounds section where you define it to be free, e.g., `x1 free`, SoPlex claims unboundedness and provides a valid primal ray.

Answer (score 2):

This model is not unbounded. There are implicit bounds of 0 on all variables, so the only feasible and hence optimal solution is the one SoPlex returns.

In the `.lp` data format, all variables are non-negative by default.